# Weird Situations with my website! Not opening on my end

Tags: wordpress

2 days back I setup a website on wordpress and this website works fine for next 48 hours but after 48 hours. It is not working on my Samsung Galaxy S6, and My windows desktop, But it is working on my Macbook. It is weird.
I've contacted to the webhosting company and they said that it is working fine on our end. So, they are unable to replicate the issue. Please help me out guys.
The URL of the website is crazyfunnyquotes.com
I'm using Wordpress + sharedhosting + cloudflare

Comment: Site is loading but not the content. Please check whether you are using the plugin properly in the home page.

Comment: there is no content on it

Comment: Works fine from my end.